# How do I ensure I get the same npm packages?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

So I have an application whose tests are not passing. The hypothesis is that the machine I cloned it to had a different version of node, so I changed the node/npm version to the one equal to the machine where the Mocha tests are passing. I assumed that would download the same exact packages as the original machine, but it doesn't, not even when I remove the caret on the package version numbers and not even if I do an `rm -rf node_modules`.

How do I ensure that I have the same exact packages? Including the packages that depend on the packages on `package.json` file.

The test that is failing is the following one:

```
the error is:  expected 400 to equal 201
      1) should create and get notes for a patient? /api/v2/patients/:patientId/notes


  27 passing (3s)
  1 pending
  1 failing

  1) Testing patients end points.
       given an user
         should create and get notes for a patient? /api/v2/patients/:patientId/notes:
     Error: Internal server error: expected 400 to equal 201
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/testutils/auth.utils.ts:226:11)
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at fulfilled (test/testutils/auth.utils.ts:5:58)
      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Which is I believe, referring to this method:

```
export async function createPatientNote(
  tokenObjectDto: TokenObjectDto,
  patientPui: string,
  noteText: string,
  isPublic: boolean,
  noteType: NoteType,
  visibleAfter?: Date,
  title?: string
): Promise<ViewNoteDto> {
  
  const urlPath = p().api.v2.patients.$patientId.notes.$url.replace(':patientId', patientPui)
  
  const newNoteDto = new NewNoteDto(
    patientPui,
    noteType,
    noteText,
    !isPublic,
    visibleAfter,
    title,
    [
      new class implements ITag {
        key = 'Test';
        value = `createPatientNode for ${patientPui}`;
      }
    ]
  )
  
  const res = await request(app)
    .post(urlPath)
    .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + tokenObjectDto.token)
    .send(newNoteDto);
    
  expect(res.status).to.equal(StatusCodes.CREATED);
  
  const viewNoteDto = res.body
  
  expect(viewNoteDto.pui).equal(patientPui)
  
  return viewNoteDto
}
```

This is the `package-lock.json` file:
https://gist.github.com/ldco2016/3bb682442b6d16976f8ffbd4ec53809d

It seems to throw an error before or on attempt to to execute the `urlPath`.

Comment: This is what package-lock.json is for.  Use it with `npm ci` to get repeatable installs

Comment: An interesting situation... I think your question would benefit from a bit of explanation as to why you absolutely, 1,000% need to have *exact*-matching package versions (major releases and incompetent maintainers aside), and what tests specifically are failing due to mismatched package versions. Minimum versions are all well and good, but packages are meant to be modular for lots of reasons (compatibility, security hotfixes/patches, among others). I would agree with @Joe's comment that you might want to focus on the integrity of `package-lock.json` versus `package.json`.

Comment: @Joe, so I need to get that other machines `package-lock.json` file.

Comment: For an application, that is generally a file you want to keep in source control with the code. That allows for repeatable installs over time.

Comment: @Joe, I cloned the project and a `package-lock.json` file was not included

Comment: @esqew, I totally get your question. I am being told the reason the tests are failing is because of version mismatch which makes no sense to me. I am being told tests pass on the other machine so it must be a package version mismatch. I have found this hard to believe from the start, but I have fixed all internal bugs and I keep being told tests are passing on that machine.

Comment: Unfortunately without the knowledge of *which* tests are failing or a `package-lock.json` to test with, it's nearly impossible to corroborate or disprove the assertion that it's due solely to mis-matched package versions. There are a near-innumerable amount of environmental factors that could also contribute to tests failing (depending on what your stack looks like and how well your execution environments mirror each other).

Comment: @esqew, I should be getting the `package-lock.json` file late on, but I added the test that is failing to the OP.

Comment: The test output you've added should have generated some sort of log from the server application itself indicating why the server threw a `400` status code instead of `201` - is that available to you as well? If there was an error in parsing the request itself that could be an indication that the networking stack on the test machine differs from that of the development machine(s) and presents the content of the requests to your code ever so slightly differently.

Comment: @esqew, so the answer is no to some sort of log, so I will have to use breakpoints I guess to debug the failing test. I did add the `package-lock.json` file.

Comment: @esqew, you shared "If there was an error in parsing the request itself that could be an indication that the networking stack on the test machine differs from that of the development machine(s) and presents the content of the requests to your code ever so slightly differently." I am not following, what do you mean?